# Javascript: prototype attribute not visible on parent

Tags: javascript, prototype

Example taken from here: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/

I also asked a similar question here: [Javascript: Added function does not appear on parent object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486704).

Create an object

```
>function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Add an attribute as a prototype. The new **kind** attribute does not appear on the object.

```
>Person.prototype.kind = 'person'

>Person
<function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Now create a new object using the parent as the prototype. The added attribute is visible.

```
var zack = new Person('Zack');

Person {name: "Zack", kind: "person"}
```

Why is the added kind attribute not visible on the parent **Person** object, even though it can convey it to children?

Comment: What is exacly your problem? it's not quite clear. What result did you expect?

Comment: My question is why cannot I see the added attribute on the original parent object.

Comment: I'm confused. Why/how do you expect `Person` to change? The prototype object only effects the objects *created* by the constructor function, not the function itself. Mutating the prototype object does not magically change the constructor function. Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript . FYI `function Person` does not create an object (like you mean it). It creates a constuctor function which lets you create objects.

Comment: So the prototype object (Person + kind) is different from the constructor function? How can I see all the attributes of a prototype? (ie: like a class + superclass in other languages)

Comment: `console.dir(Func.prototype)` . If you also want to see *instance properties*, you have to create an instance: `console.dir(new Func())`. The prototype object is the object shared by all instances created by the constructor function. It's their "prototype".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beceause Person is just a funtion(object)/Constructor:

```
Person =
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

To Get the kind object on person refer to the prototype

```
Person.prototype =
Person {kind: "person"}
```

Im not an expert in this but if you would want to create a new constructor you should overwrite the function.

You could see the function (below) as an constructor to set instance specific variables

```
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

`Person.prototype.kind = 'person'` is like a static variable on the class

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the `Person` Constructor.

To look at the properties of the definition of a `Person` you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person.prototype)`

This would show the `kind` property.